# Is there a difference between using 「である」 and 「の」 before 「はず」?

Tags: grammar, verbs, formal-nouns

Is there a difference in meaning between using 「である」 and 「の」 before 「はず」?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning between the two:

> Both 「～～**である**はず」 and 「～～**の**はず」 mean "**expected to be ~~**", "***must be ~~***", etc.

**The difference is basically in the formality.  The former is more formal than the latter**.

One more "difference" I would like to mention is regarding what words can precede the two expressions.

Nouns can precede both 「～～**である**はず」 and 「～～**の**はず」 with no problems.  You can say either 「スミスさん**である**はず」 or 「スミスさん**の**はず」 to mean "has got to be Mr./Ms. Smith".

The stems of na-adjectives can only precede 「～～**である**はず」 as in 「きれいであるはず」.　Careful speakers would ***not*** say 「きれい**の**はず」 because they would say 「きれい**な**はず」.

Finally, i-adjectives and verbs ***cannot*** directly precede either of the two expressions in question.  Those can only directly precede just 「はず」 as in  「かわいい**はず** ♡」、「来{く}る**はず**」, etc.

Comment: おや、こっちにも11時37分に仕返しDVが